# Sending JSON in POST from WP8 to AppEngine - Error 500

Tags: c#, json, google-app-engine, http-post, windows-phone-8

Hi I'm trying to send the following JSON string to AppEngine server. The string looks as following:

```
{"param2":50.0,"param1":50.0,"additionalParams":{"param3":"123","userID":"1234561"}}
```

And the code that I use for sending it is below:

```
public async Task<string> SendJSONData(string urlToCall, string JSONData)
    {
        // server to POST to
        string url = urlToCall;

        // HTTP web request
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "action";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Write the request Asynchronously 
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                                 httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            //create some json string
            string json = JSONData;

            // convert json to byte array
            byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // Write the bytes to the stream
            await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String webResponse = requestReader.ReadToEnd();
        return webResponse;
}
```

I've sniffed what is being sent to the server, using Fiddler:

```
POST http://server.appspot.com/method HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 85
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: action
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: server.appspot.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache

{"param2":50.0,"param1":50.0,"additionalParams":{"param3":"123","userID":"1234561"}}
```

Please mind that I've expeimented with "Content-Type" parameter, setting it to both "text/plain" and "application/json". 
Still the answer from the server looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 18:54:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 466


<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>If the            problem persists, please <A HREF="http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html">report</A> your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.</h2>
```

What should I do, to receive the desired "OK" response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the lack of "action" parameter in my POST.
Workaround looks like this:

```
    // Write the request Asynchronously 
    using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>
    (httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
    {
        //create some json string
        string json = "action="+JSONData;

        // convert json to byte array
        byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        // Write the bytes to the stream
        await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
    }
```